# Params sent through integration test case to the service having an issue:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: java, grails

I am running an integration test of a service.

My service has code something like this:

```
def a(params){
 def b = params.list('checkNotification')
 def c = params.balance}
```

Here different values from params have been fetched in two different ways.

Now while sending params from test as in following code:

```
def params = [checkNotification : ['email2','email3'],
             balance: 11]
when:
 service.saveSomething(params)
```

I am getting an error:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:java.util.ArrayList.list() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [checkNotification]

How can I send params of this type to the service?

I am using Grails 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Your test case sends parameter *params*, which is a map with two keys *checkNotification* and *balance*

Just access the *checkNotification* list the same way as you access *balance*.

```
def b = params.checkNotification
def c = params.balance
```